# Passing JavaScript array using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, arrays

I'm very new to ajax and I'm trying to pass an array that I have created in javascript called markers over to a PHP page when the user clicks the submit button. At the time of submission the array exists and is within scope. The code below is what is trying to do that. When I click the submit button I get sent to the php page and "failed" is printed (part of my code) meaning the array was not passed. I believe the error occurs in the ajax code and I'm not sure where it is coming from, any help is greatly appreciated!

The javascript/ajax stuff:

```
function submit_tour(){
    var input = JSON.stringify(markers);
    //var input = $(this).serialize();
    var sent = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: input,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: "test_portal2.php"
            }).done(function() {window.alert("done");})
            .fail(function() {window.alert("failed");});
    window.alert("" + input);
}
```

The HTML button that is supposed to send the array:

```
<form name="toursubmit" action="test_portal2.php" onsubmit="submit_tour()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The PHP that catches it (in the test_portal.php file):

```
$ans = json_decode($sent);
echo $ans;
if ($ans != NULL){
    echo "works";
    echo $ans;
}
else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: There's no need to serialize the object to a JSON string, the jQuery.ajax method will handle that for you. So you can get away with data: markers and no specific dataType property. My next question is what is the value of "markers"?

Comment: How are you populating `$sent`?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to point out.

First, you need to prevent the default POST action within your `submit_tour()` function, otherwise the synchronous POST will happen.

Second, you need to specify the contentType value in your AJAX call as `application/json`.

Third, if you are actually POSTing JSON to PHP and using `application/json` as the ContentType, then you will need to get the JSON data in PHP by accessing the raw input like this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

This is because `$_POST` is only auto-generated for form-encoded content types.

Answer (score 1):

When you send

```
var input = JSON.stringify(markers);
```

And markers has no value

```
<input type="hidden" id="markers" name="markers">     // No value anywhere
```

Then it will surely be Null :)

Also do you populate your `$sent` variable from a value in `$_POST` ? don't see that happening

Comment: The array is not null, I tested for that as well. That is why I know it is not getting passed.

Comment: What is the value of `input` variable after `stringify` line?

Comment: it is the string value of the array. I believe stringify turns the array into a string

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this in a form tag. The code is submitting the form and not running the JS.

Remove the form tag, or put this: submit_tour(); in onsubmit on the form instead, and return false.

Comment: I changed my HTML above a bit, is this what you mean? I don't think this is where the error is coming from since it seems to be executing the function okay but the array is not getting to the php file.

Comment: "When I click the submit button I get sent to the php page and "failed" is printed" This shouldn't happen. There is no point having an AJAX function when you are actually submitting to the PHP page. This is what Mike is reffering to when he correctly says "First, you need to prevent the default POST action within your submit_tour() function, otherwise the synchronous POST will happen."